# Cross-browser JQuery UI DatePicker with Html.EditorFor

Tags: jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC4 application, I have a view with "from" and "to" fields, for which I use a JQuery UI DatePicker control.
I'm using HtmlHelper to build my form, as the following code shows:

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CustomerId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "Id", "Name"))
    <span class="datePicker">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FromDate)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FromDate)
    </span>
    <span class="datePicker">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ToDate)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ToDate)
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsActiveOnly)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsActiveOnly)
</p>
```

On the model, I use the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attributes for the two DateTime properties, **which renders the DatePicker correctly in Chrome - but without the default values - but not in IE or FF**.

Is there a way to work with HtmlHelper (or with minimal JS) to display the DatePicker in all 3 browsers?

Answer (score 1):

why not set the `datePicker` class to the texboxes as passing it to the `TextBoxFor` method's objectHtml attribute

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:d}", new {  @class = "datePicker"})
```

**EDIT :**

As as example to the above solution

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.MVCTEST2
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".datePicker").datepicker();
    })
</script>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "datePicker" })
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

TESTED on IE FF and GC

Comment: run this script 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".datePicker").datepicker();
});

Comment: Sorry, same result.  I'm getting a plain textbox with the default date value.

Comment: using firebug please ensure that the current text box has class `hasDatepicker`

Comment: Yes, it has this class.  Can you please provide a working code sample so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: plz comment is issue is not resolved or if resolved plz accept the answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response.  I took your code as-is and I'm still seeing a plain textbox with the date inside.  I commented out all attributes I had on the model properties to make sure it's not the cause for not getting the editor.  Do you have any idea what could be my problem?

Comment: The only reason i could figure out is that the script is not getting fired. The reason may be that your client does not get the required scripts or the sequence may be wrong.
If your html control has the class `hasDatepicker` and you have corectly included the jquerycore and jqueryui scripts with your page the thing must work. The datepicker has nothing to do with the razor engine plz confirm the existence of `hasDatepicker` class and the script file in sequence(core then UI) at client end. Also esure that java script is enable in the browser in which you are testing

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  I'll try to figure out the above.